# How to query the age of an ARP-cache entry in Linux

Tags: linux-networking, arp

How can I query the local ARP-cache on my Linux-machine to see when a specific ARP-entry was learned and/or updated the last time?

Comment: I don't have a reference on hand but IIRC that isn't recorded by default and you'd need to install something like arpwatch

Comment: Thanks for this idea @HBruijn . Then I would have to parse the syslog to keep track of the arp neighbors. I thought there was an arp cache timeout anyway which I could use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ip -statistics neighbour` gives some interesting information. When called with `watch` one number seems to increment once per second, and resets to zero when a new arp exchange takes place.

```
Every 2.0s: ip -statistics neighbour                              Sat Oct 14 02:09:42 2017

fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XX25 dev enp2s1 lladdr dc:XX:XX:XX:XX:25 router used >35</39/21 probes 0 STALE
10.0.0.1 dev enp2s1 lladdr dc:XX:XX:XX:XX:25 ref 1 used >5586</0/434 probes 1 REACHABLE
```

Marked with >< are the numbers that increment with time.

Answer (score 0):

(can not comment ... searched a longer time for following information and would like to share it here, as it may help)

As Robbie showed:

```
ip -statistics neighbour
```

has output triplet

```
5586/0/434
```

which means "last used"/"last confirmed"/"last updated", so here the output means: entry was last used 5586 seconds ago, confirmed 0 seconds ago, updated 434 seconds ago (source: e.g. http://www.policyrouting.com/iproute2.doc.html); so i think the second number gives the seconds back to the last confirmed contact ... if the status is REACHABLE (?).
Maybe [When do STALE arp entries become FAILED when never used?](https://serverfault.com/questions/765380/when-do-stale-arp-entries-become-failed-when-never-used) will be helpful here too for more details.